# Haskell - infinite list -

Tags: list, haskell, infinite

I have this data and types:

```
data Cliente = Uncliente {nombre::String,resistencia::Int,bebidas::[Bebida],amigos::[Cliente]} deriving (Show) 

type Bebida = Cliente -> Cliente 

type Nombre = String
type Duracion = Float
type Acciones = [Bebida]
type Itinerario = (Nombre,Duracion,Acciones)
```

And I have this slogan:

"Define chuckNorris, who is a customer who was initially called "Chuck", has resistance 1000, is Ana's friend and took all sodas that exist in the universe, starting with a level 1 soda, then a level 2 soda, and So on."

and i do:

```
chuckNorris = Uncliente {
    nombre = "Chuck",
    resistencia = 1000,
    bebidas = [soda 1,2..],
    amigos = [ana]
```

But this does not work because the infinite list of drinks is not like that

How would you write the infinite list?

like soda 1, soda 2, soda 3 ........

Answer (score 3):

I'd write it as `map soda [1,2..]`

`map` effectively takes each element in the list (1, 2, 3 and so on) and applies `soda` to it, resulting in another list with `soda 1`, `soda 2`, `soda 3` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is via the `map` function. Infinite lists which step by `1` can be done with the `..` syntax.

```
map soda [1..]
```

This is semantically equivalent to something like

```
[soda 1, soda 2, soda 3, {- and so on... -}]
```

The reason this works is thanks to Haskell's lazy evaluation.  The calls to `soda` only occur once you start traversing the infinite list, so no need to fear getting caught in an infinite loop here.